# Find All paths using Dijkstra algorithm in prolog

Tags: prolog, dijkstra

I have an assignment using Dijkstra algorithm.
This algorithm allows me to calculate a single optimal path of a graph, but, i 
wish to calculate all paths that use a time not exceeding a certain given limit without modifying the algorithm(but using it). I have no idea how to do that in Prolog.

**Here is my code.**

```
     dijkstra([Time-[To|RPath] |_], To, [To|RPath], Time) :- !.

     dijkstra(Visited, To, RPath, Time) :-
       best_candidate(Visited, BestCandidate), 
       dijkstra([BestCandidate|Visited], To, RPath, Time).

     best_candidate(VisitedPaths, BestCandidate) :-
        findall( 
            P,
            (   member(Len-[State1|Path], VisitedPaths),
                arc(State1, State2, Time),       
                \+ is_visited(VisitedPaths, State2),
                NewTime is Len + Time,               
                P = NewTime-[State2,State1|Path] 
            ),                                        
             Candidates
        ),

          minimum(Candidates, BestCandidate).

     % ex: minimum([0-[3,2], 4-[1]], M).  ---->  M = 0-[3, 2].
     minimum(List, Min) :-
        keysort(List, [Min|_]).
          %member(Chemin,List).

     is_visited(VisitedPaths, State) :-
        memberchk(_-[State|_], VisitedPaths).
```

**This is my principal predicate**

```
      shortest_path(From, To, Path, Time) :-
      dijkstra([0-[From]], To, RPath, Time),
      reverse(RPath, Path).
```

**I have tried**

```
findall(Path,shortest_path(From, To, Path, Time),PathList).
member(X,PathList).
```

But X gives me the same paths multiple times.. not sure whats going on (The algorithm works for sure and the implementation of the graph / edges too.)

Comment: Can you post your input data, e.g the graph?

Comment: `shortest_path(state(pos(1, 1), room1, nothing), state(pos(1, 2), room1, Item), Path,Time).` Like this? @damianodamiano

Comment: And it returns me : `Item = nothing,`
`Path = [state(pos(1, 1), room1, nothing), state(pos(1, 2), room1, nothing)],`
`Time = 1.`

Comment: for example, i also want the path :`Path = [state(pos(1, 1), room1, nothing), state(pos(2, 1), room1, nothing),state(pos(2, 2), room1, nothing),state(pos(1, 2), room1, nothing)]` in a square room 2x2 for examble, where `pos(Line,Column)`

Comment: @Hazel it would be best if you edit your question to include those details. They are hard to find for readers in the comments, so the comments are not an appropriate place to put them.